# "502 bad gateway error nginx" - web app working in http://itrendsolution.org:5000 but cant redirect "itrendsolution.org" to this address

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy, vps, bad-gateway

My web app runs in http://191.101.1.48:5000
My domain itrendsolution.org has IP address 191.101.1.48 [correctly pointing]
but when i visit itrendsolution.org it shows "502 Bad gateway error nginx".
I use cloudpanel (VPS hosting) to host the Flask web app , which has connection with MySql.

I used Nginx , so that when one visits https://itrendsolution.org they get redirected to the web app which runs in port 5000 in http [http://191.101.1.48:5000] through "proxy pass" of nginx configuration.

I do have ssl certificate . still when i visit itrendsolution.org its not working. it shows "502 bad gateway error nginx"
How to make a web app running in http://191.101.1.48:5000 to get run in https://191.101.1.48 or itrendsolution.org ?

i tried nginx configuration to redirect.

nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name itrendsolution.org www.itrendsolution.org;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name itrendsolution.org www.itrendsolution.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/itrendsolution.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/itrendsolution.org/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://191.101.1.48:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Additional SSL settings
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # Additional configurations if needed

    location ~ /\.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Show your nginx virtual host config, please

Comment: server {
    listen 80;
    server_name itrendsolution.org www.itrendsolution.org;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name itrendsolution.org www.itrendsolution.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/itrendsolution.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/itrendsolution.org/privkey.pem;
location / {
        proxy_pass http://191.101.1.48:5000;

Comment: proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location ~ /\.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You should specify protocol in proxy_pass, e.g. `proxy_pass http://191.101.1.48:5000;`
If nginx and your app are running on the same host, you can try to use
`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;`

Comment: I have used both "proxy_pass http://191.1.48:5000" and also "http://127.0.0.1:5000" in location / { .
 Both are not working.

Comment: Do you use http:// prefix in proxy_pass? It is missing in config that you provided. What error is logged in /var/log/nginx/error.log ?

Comment: yes. i have used http:// (its hidden here)

Comment: The Nginx error log shows:

Several informational messages about ngx_pagespeed, indicating no threading with "1 Rewrite, 1 Expensive Rewrite" and rollback of gzip compression due to settings in nginx.conf.

Routine notices of signal processes starting, likely for Nginx restarts or reloads.

A critical SSL handshake error ("bad key share") during an HTTPS connection attempt, suggesting issues with SSL configuration or key exchange.

Comment: Why did you decide to omit `http://` prefix when posting your config? Nginx error log should show info  about unavailable upstream regarding your 502 error. Unless you have separate logs for this vhost, but i don’t see anything like that in your config. Can you post full config file with proper formatting of your vhost  by editing original question?

Comment: in this comment section , "http" prefix is cutting down automatically, but i have included that in my nginx. here i have edited the question for your reference.

Comment: Please check that `191.101.1.48:5000` is available from server running nginx.  
You can use, for example, this command (run it on the server which runs nginx) `telnet  191.101.1.48 5000` to check connectivity - it should open network connection if that port is available. 
Also, please check again nginx  error log, what is the output of `grep "191.101.1.48" /var/log/nginx/error.log | tail -n 3`  command?

Comment: for "telnet  191.101.1.48 5000" it shows :
Trying 191.101.1.48...
Connected to 191.101.1.48.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: for "grep "191.101.1.48" /var/log/nginx/error.log | tail -n 3" :
There is no output

Comment: Thank you. I’m puzzled why your error log is empty. Could you please check that nginx is actually using your https config section? Put `deny all;` before `location` line and restart nginx, would the error code change from 502 to 403 if you access `https://itrendsolution.org`